sum all the digits in the inputed number
I have to do a program that sum all the digits in the inputed number: for example:
input -> 29
return -> 11
29 = (2 + 9 = 11)
def superdigito(y):
    # Enquanto o número tiver mais de um dígito
    while y >= 10:
        digitosSum = 0
        # Calcula a soma dos dígitos
        while y > 0:
            digitosSum += y % 10
            y //= 10
        # Atualiza o número para a soma dos dígitos
        y = digitosSum
    return y

# Leitura do número inteiro pelo teclado
y = int(input("Digite um número inteiro: "))
# Calcula e imprime o superdígito do número
print("Todos os dígitos somados:", superdigito(y))


I tried this but whenever I input "29", the program returns me "2".

What's the outer loop for (while y >= 10:)? Try without it.

don't replace y with your sum and just return the sum at the end (no y = digitosSum) and just return digitosSum at the en

Minimal solution:  sum(map(int,str(n))) where n is a non-negative integer.

For a value that is >= 0:
def superdigito(y):
    r = 0
    while y > 0:
        r += y % 10
        y //= 10
    return r


Another solution that’s faster than all existing answers:
def sum_digits(s):
   return sum(map(ord, s)) - 48 * len(s)

The function takes a string because that’s what you get from input().
ord("1") is a lot faster than int("1"), but it has an offset of 48 (ASCII code for 0). This solution applies ord on each character, then subtract 48 for each one.
According to timeit; using a string input:



Solution
Best time (seconds for 1M iterations; the lower the better)




This answer
0.48


@SIGHUP’s answer with a division in a loop
0.72


sum(map(int, s))
1.15


sum([int(c) for c in s])
1.38


sum(int(c) for c in s)
1.56




You could loop over each digit in y:
def superdigito(y):
    return sum([int(digit) for digit in str(y).strip()])


print(superdigito(29))

Out:
11


Functionally correct but woefully inefficient

convert the integer to string and sum over each character when you convert character back to integer.
number = 129

number_string = str(number)
number_sum = 0
for character in number_string:
  number_sum += int(character)

print(number_sum)


Why are you working with strings?

Easy implementation? No need to do divs and mods

I would recommend looping through the length of an inputted number (x) and summing each individual value:
For example:
x = input() 
sum = 0
for digit in x:
       sum += int(digit)
print(sum)


The input value in the OP is clearly int - not a string. Why are you shadowing sum()?

This code allows any number inputted to be converted to the sum of its digits, and since the initial input will be a string it needs to be converted to an integer. I'm just using sum a variable.

Try with an input of "abc"

@SIGHUP the input value in the question is a string; OP converts it to an int, but a solution that works on a string is perfectly fine.

@bfontaine No. The function signature in OP is effectively def superdigito(y:int) -> int: He takes a string (from input()), converts that to int then passes that to superdigito()

@SIGHUP the question starts with "I have to do a program", not "I have to do a function".

@bfontaine True but it's the function that's flawed
